# Align label to the left of Bootstrap Toggle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap toggle to create switches like so:

```
<form>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" checked="checked" />
            Toggle Text Right
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            Toggle Text Left
            <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" />
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Is there a way to move the label to the left of the switch? I tried by putting the text before the input, but it doesn't fit well.

http://jsfiddle.net/sjxd1vpt/2/

Answer (score 1):

Or if you do not specifically need the label tag you could use a span.

```
<form>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" checked="checked" />
    <span>
        Toggle Text Right
    </span>
</div>

<div class="checkbox">
    <span>
        Toggle Text Left
    </span>
    <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" />
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: This removes the clickable functionality of label

Answer (score 0):

It appears the bootstrap-toggle css has a margin-left: -20px;

Simply add a custom class to the desired left label like so.

```
.left .toggle {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

This will maintain the structure **Bootstrap-Toggle** expects in case they have styling tied in such as:

```
label input {
  // some input targeted styling
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sjxd1vpt/5/

Answer (score 0):

You should use bootstrap `container-fluid` wrappers to achieve the effect.

```
<form>
<div class="checkbox container-fluid" >
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" checked="checked" />
        Toggle Text Right
    </label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox container">
    <label>
        Toggle Text Left

    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" />
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: This may result in the desired output, but we can safely assume that this project already uses `container` or `container-fluid` for the general layout. With that in mind... nesting the container wrapper is something Bootstrap's developers specifically advise *against* in Bootstrap 3.x.

Comment: @RobertC There was nothing such specified in the question, he is I believe trying to create some random switches.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Bootstrap adds `float: left` to `.form-check-input`

Just override this with `float: none` and place label before input in the html.

Answer (score 0):

- Swap label and input
- set `style="display:contents"` for container div
- set `style="float:none;margin-left:0.5rem"` for input

[image]

```
<div class="form-check form-switch" style="display:contents;">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Default switch checkbox input</label>
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" style="float:none;margin-left:0.5rem">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your label tag should be closed before the input tag.

```
<form>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label> Toggle Text Right </label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" checked="checked" />
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label> Toggle Text Left </label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" />
    </div>
</form>
```

This should prevent the button toggle from overlapping on the text.

Here : http://jsfiddle.net/sjxd1vpt/4/

Comment: Note: OP is using Bootstrap-Toggle. While you are correct, caution as the library recommends the structure OP presented. http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/. This answer may break the frameworks CSS if they are using classing like `label input { Some Styles }`

Comment: @Illdapt aahh.. missed that usage of a plugin. But, still seeing the css sheet of that plugin, there is no style being applied to the label part of the element. Also, the div to which all styles are applied is perfectly outside the label content. So, humbly to my knowledge, its not breaking any CSS styles. It should be good to use.